# How to algorithmically color correct images?

Tags: algorithm, colors

What kind of algorithms are used to set color profiles on image within Lightroom. For example, you can build a color profile from a MacBeth chart with ground truth colors and apply those to a new image and the new image will appear according to the profile.

EDIT: To clarify as requested. I am specifically interested in programmatically reproducing the sort of features found in adobe Lightroom or photoshop that enable users to adjust the color of a given image based on a supplied color profile. If you don't mind, this video demonstrate precisely what I'm talking about:

https://youtu.be/C67X_09FeTY?t=170

As you can see, based on the supplied Macbeth chart, a profile can be built to adjust the color in an image. I'm looking to get a better idea of what the underlying algorithm is that makes this happen.

Comment: Please clarify all the context of your question and explain what your programming question is. Thank you.

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope for this site.

Comment: I have included a video to show what it is that I am looking to replicate. You can see how the color from the chart are applied and the image is adjusted.